# PHP regex expresion to mask multiple email

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a email in this format. I tried the regex below, i unable to mask the email after semicolon.

```
var email = "testing.123@gmail.com;testing-test2@gmail.com";
a
//using this regex
preg_replace("/(?:(?:^|(?<=@))([^.@])|\G(?!\A))[^.@](?:([^.@])(?=[.@]))?/","$1*$2",email);
a
```

The output will be

```
t*****g.123@g***l.com;testing-test2@g***l.com
```

My expected output

```
t*********3@g***l.com;t***********2@g***l.com
```

How can i achieve that? Or is there any more efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to match the two types of substrings (that is, before the `@`, and after the `@`) separately, you might consider matching both *at once*, and use `preg_replace_callback` to replace the in-between characters with `*`s:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback(
  '/(?:^|(?<=;))([^@])([^@]*)([^@]@[^.])([^.]*)(?=[^.]\.)/',
  function ($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[2])) . $matches[3] . str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[4]));
  },
  $str
);
```

https://regex101.com/r/VfS4Fh/2

The pattern

```
(?:^|(?<=;))([^@])([^@]*)([^@]@[^.])([^.]*)(?=[^.]\.)
```

means:

- `(?:^|(?<=;))` - Start at the beginning of the string, or right after a `;`
- `([^@])` - First group - capture first character
- `([^@]*)` - Second group - capture non-`@` characters (replace with `*`s later)
- `([^@]@[^.])` - Third group - capture the `@` and the characters on each side
- `([^.]*)` - Fourth group - capture non-`.` characters (replace with `*`s later)
- `(?=[^.]\.)` - Lookahead for a non-`.` character, followed by a `.`

Then, replace with the same groups in the same order, except with the second and fourth group replaced with `*`s.